# Recaptcha is not displaying for Django Registration in Django1.5

Tags: python, django, recaptcha, django-registration

I am following the post by [Maro Fucci](http://www.marcofucci.com/tumblelog/26/jul/2009/integrating-recaptcha-with-django/) for integrating ReCaptcha for my Django Registration. It worked properly in Django 1.4. However, after upgrading to Django 1.5 I got problem with class based views which I have resolved it and now I can able to render the registration form on the page. The biggest problem is the recaptcha its not rendering.

I am pasting the exact code which I have written.

**My Projects urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = patterns('',
          ) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns = patterns('',

  url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.index'),
  (r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),)
```

**My Application urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from registration.views import RegistrationView

from myapp.forms import RecaptchaRegistrationForm

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^register/$', RegistrationView.register,
    {'form_class': RecaptchaRegistrationForm},
    name='registration.RegistrationView.register'),
    (r'', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
  )
```

I have placed the `widgets.py` and `fields.py` which was posted in Marco Fucci page inside the myapp folder and `myapp.forms.py` looks like this

```
from django import forms
from myapp.fields import ReCaptchaField 
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
class RecaptchaRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
      recaptcha = ReCaptchaField()
```

I have printed the registration form using the `manage.py` it prints registration form with recaptcha as shown below

```
>>> from myapp.forms import RecaptchaRegistrationForm
>>> p = RecaptchaRegistrationForm()
>>> print p
<tr class="required"><th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th><td><input id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr class="required"><th><label for="id_email">E-mail:</label></th><td><input id="id_email" name="email" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr class="required"><th><label for="id_password1">Password:</label></th><td><input id="id_password1" name="password1" type="password" /></td></tr>
<tr class="required"><th><label for="id_password2">Password (again):</label></th><td><input id="id_passwo" name="password2" type="password" /></td></tr>
<tr class="required"><th><label for="id_recaptcha">Recaptcha:</label></th><td> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LcPF-KEY"></script>
```

But when I call `http://localhost:8000/accounts/register/` from browser recaptcha is not rendering. The registration form is not inheriting the Recaptcha. May be I am doing something stupid. Can some one guide me please.

Comment: Do you think something wrong with the templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a [class based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage-in-your-urlconf) in your url patterns, point your url pattern to the `as_view()` method. You can't just include the `RegistrationView.register` method directly.

To customize the behaviour of `RegistrationView`, subclass it, and set the `form_class` attribute.

```
class RecaptchaRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    """
    Subclass of RegistrationView that uses RecaptchaRegistrationForm
    """
    form_class = RecaptchaRegistrationForm

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^register/$', RecaptchaRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
```

Comment: I have added the registration `RecaptchaRegistrationView` in `registration.views` and changed the urlpatterns. But still its not rendering

Comment: Might be I am doing something wrong. I will reverify. However, I can able to call rest of classes properly viz., `login`,`reset`,`forgot`

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure (by debugging) that your RecaptchaRegistrationForm is getting picked up when you are calling the register view.

And also,
The public key in the rendered html seems to be wrong.
6LcPF-KEY

Comment: Printing ReCaptcha is rendering as shown in my question. I have just truncated the public key.

Comment: Ok, so the final html rendered by the view has ReCaptcha script in it?

Comment: Yes. I am trying the below solution

Comment: If the ReCaptcha script is present in final web page, that means there is nothing wrong in the python code. Please check if there are any javascript errors. 
I rendered the html output you have posted and it worked for me.